# Webcenter Sites - JSK Installation

Tags: wcs, webcenter-sites

I am trying to install JSK 11.1.1.8 on mac x yosemite with Java 1.8.

After installation; while trying to run jsk, i am getting the following error,

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   oracle.fatwire.sites.jsk.Execute

I tried the solution provided in the [blog](http://anothermiddleware.blogspot.com/2013/11/starting-oracle-webcenter-sites-jsk.html), still not working..

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: I have installed all version of WCS JSK on my MAC, it works perfectly with no ussue. At what step are you stuck? Any errors in sites.log? Note: For WCS 11.1.1.8.0 and older, you will need JAVA 1.7 but for latest JSK 12c, you will need JAVA 1.8

Answer (score 1):

I never install JSK on Mac but installed several times on Windows. That error seems that you don´t have the jar that contains that class.

Verify what is the name of the jar and if you have it on App_Server\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\Sites\webapps\cs\WEB-INF\lib